# How can I get my bootstrap navbar background color to span the entire width of my page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a fiddle here that shows a navbar. The navbar spans most of the page but not all. I want the background color to span the entire width of the page (not the links, just the background color, so width: 100% on background color, but I tried menupartial width 100% and it doesn't work in the css. Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldqabe1x/1/)

```css
body {
  padding-top: 51px;
  /*padding-bottom: 20px;*/
}
/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */

.front-page-body-content {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/

.dl-horizontal dt {
  white-space: normal;
}
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */

input,
select,
textarea {
  max-width: 280px;
}
.navbar-inline {
  display: inline-flex;
}
#navbarSearchQuery {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  min-width: 280px;
}
@@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  #navbarSearchQuery {
    min-width: 240px;
  }
}
#searchQuery {
  /*float: left;*/
  margin-top: 10px;
  /*margin-left: 15px;*/
  min-width: 280px;
}
a.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
form#queryWithin {
  max-height: 50px;
}
#ClassDate {
  cursor: default;
}
.menupartial {
  background-color: #16749F;
  opacity: .9;
  width: 100%;
}
.menupartial a {
  color: lightgrey;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.nav-pills > li > a:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #16749F;
  color: white;
}
.nav-pills > li > a:active {
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container body-content">
    <div class="row menupartial">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">

          <li><a href="#">Your Schedules</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Your Messages</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Your Groups</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Your Friends</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `container` to `container-fluid` and move the `menupartial` to that div like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid menupartial">
```

**`container-fluid`** is the default Bootstrap class for spanning the container to full-width.

Here's a jsFiddle with the above class: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/49/

Comment: Starting from Bootstrap 3, fluid is the default behavior and an explicit container-fluid declaration is not needed, instead of `<div class="container-fluid menupartial">` `<div class="menupartial">` will work, too

Answer (score 0):

Set the body left/right margins to 0:

```
body {
  padding-top: 51px;
  /*padding-bottom: 20px;*/
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `container` to `container-fluid` and then move `menupartial` to your `column`. And you can remove 100% from the `menupartial` rule. See example.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 51px;
  /*padding-bottom: 20px;*/
}
/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */

.front-page-body-content {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/

.dl-horizontal dt {
  white-space: normal;
}
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */

input,
select,
textarea {
  max-width: 280px;
}
.navbar-inline {
  display: inline-flex;
}
#navbarSearchQuery {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  min-width: 280px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #navbarSearchQuery {
    min-width: 240px;
  }
}
#searchQuery {
  /*float: left;*/
  margin-top: 10px;
  /*margin-left: 15px;*/
  min-width: 280px;
}
a.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
form#queryWithin {
  max-height: 50px;
}
#ClassDate {
  cursor: default;
}
.body-content .menupartial {
  background-color: #16749F;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.body-content .menupartial a {
  color: lightgrey;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav.nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.nav.nav-pills > li > a:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #16749F;
  color: white;
}
.nav.nav-pills > li > a:active {
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid body-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 menupartial">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li><a href="#">Your Schedules</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Your Messages</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Your Groups</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Your Friends</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Div>
</body>
```